# Get more then one value xPath

Tags: python, xpath

I don't know xPath very well, but i can write simple xpath's.

Some time ago, i write a few regex for one easy task, but now i interest, how i can write one  xPath for this task or just say, how i can select more then one path in one xpath...

```
<div class="h2"><a href="/?cat=1" title="the cat1">cat1</a></div>
<div>
    <a href="/?to=1321" title="parent cat1">cat1</a>
    <a href="/?to=324"  title="child elem1" class="a2">elem1</a>
    <a href="/?to=33"   title="child elem2" class="a2">elem2</a>

    <a href="/?to=1"    title="parent cat2">cat2</a>
    <a href="/?to=43"   title="child elem1" class="a2">elem1</a>
    <a href="/?to=879"  title="child elem2" class="a2">elem2</a>
    <a href="/?to=768"  title="child elem3" class="a2">elem3</a>

    <a href="/?to=017"  title="parent cat3">cat3</a>
    <a href="/?to=241"  title="child elem1" class="a2">elem1</a>
</div>
```

And my regex return this. And now i want, that xpath return the same result (list&dict -> JSON).

```
[
   {
      "href":"/?cat=1",
      "title":"the cat1",
      "anchor":"cat1",
      "childrens":[
         {
            "href":"/?cat=1321",
            "title":"parent cat1",
            "anchor":"cat1",
            "childrens":[
               {
                  "href":"/?to=324",
                  "title":"child elem1",
                  "anchor":"elem1"
               },
               {
                  "href":"/?to=33",
                  "title":"child elem2",
                  "anchor":"elem2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "href":"/?cat=1",
            "title":"parent cat2",
            "anchor":"cat2",
            "childrens":[
               {
                  "href":"/?to=43",
                  "title":"child elem1",
                  "anchor":"elem1"
               },
               {
                  "href":"/?to=879",
                  "title":"child elem2",
                  "anchor":"elem2"
               },
               {
                  "href":"/?to=768",
                  "title":"child elem3",
                  "anchor":"elem3"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "href":"/?cat=017",
            "title":"parent cat3",
            "anchor":"cat3",
            "childrens":[
               {
                  "href":"/?to=241",
                  "title":"child elem1",
                  "anchor":"elem1"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: i can't see any regex. and no child elements of any `<a>`-tag.

Comment: Please post your regex set and XPath attempts if you have any. Also, `children` is plural form for `child`, so there's no plural-plural form `childrens`